# Jetpack Compose Lazy Column is stretching items when end of list is reached

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Why my `LazyColumn` items are being stretched?

```kotlin
class RecipeListFragment: Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: RecipeListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                val recipes = viewModel.recipes.value

                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                    Text(
                        text = "RecipeList",
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 21.sp
                        )
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            findNavController().navigate(R.id.viewRecipe)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "TO RECIPE FRAGMENT")
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                    LazyColumn{
                        items(recipes) { recipe ->
                            // RecipeCard(recipe = recipe, onClick = {})
                            Text(
                                text = recipe.title ?: "None",
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider submitting a bug about this to https://goo.gle/compose-feedback

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it can be reproduced in a clean project. Your current code works fine on the latest Compose version.

Comment: I've updated the example to include the entire class.

Comment: Post your MaterialTheme.typography.h5

Answer (score 1):

android 12 preview versions prior to ~august build have this problem.

More info can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208694349

Try on the stable android12 and/or on the real device

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavior has happened to me. The reason wasn't compose/material versions, but I was using an old version of Smartlook library. I don't why it affected other widgets!! But after updating it everything was working as expected.

So, anybody who faces this uncommon behavior, he might need to update his old dependencies.